# jQuery assertion support / defensive programming?

Tags: jquery, debugging

Is there any built in support in jQuery for basic assertion checking, primarily of things like 'expected number of returned elements'.

For instance I may have a simple statement like this :

```
 $("#btnSignup").click(function() {
     return validateForm();
 );
```

Now theres plenty of reasons why `$("#btnSignup")` may not return exactly 1 item :

- You mistyped the button id name
- Somebody renamed it by mistake
- It doesnt exist on the page
- There are TWO elements with that id by mistake
- You are using ASP.NET MVC and you accidentally generated the HTML for the button with `HtmlHelper.Button(...)` instead of `HtmlHelper.Submit()`. The `Button(...)` method does NOT create an ID for the button element.

Now in this instance (and many instances) my application simply won't work unless EXACTLY one item is returned from the selector. So i ALWAYS want to be told if `$("@#btnSignup")` doesn't return exactly 1 item. So how can I do this?! I'm fine if this is an exception or preferably an alert box - so if I'm not running in a debugger then I can be told.

I'm looking for syntax somthing like this - which is similar in functionality to .NET's [`Single()`](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/SingleOperator.ashx) extension method.

```
 $("#btnSignup").assertSingle().click(function() {
     return validateForm();
 );

 or 

 $("#btnSignup").assertSize(1).click(function() {
     return validateForm();
 );
```

I'd personally be fine for this code to ALWAYS run and tell whoever is there that there is a problem. its obviously not a [performance issue](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001218.html) to be running this extra code for all eternity. In this instance my code is broken if `#btnSignup` doesn't exist.

I'm sure this issue has been beaten to death and there are many solutions - but can somebody point me to some of them?

I dont see anything built into jQuery and would wonder what the best plugin is. I'd much rather just have something on the page that can keep 'watching' over me and tell me if theres an issue. I wouldn't even be opposed to an AJAX call being made to an error reporting service.

Comment: Not that my life depends on it, but an up-vote/accept would be nice nevertheless. ;-)

Comment: @tomalak you know i actually think i DID click on it but i think it was cos my intenet was being flaky and i was too busy testing it to notice your vote didnt go through. i was getting 7kb/s upstream and 58.34kb/s downstream on a cable modem. either case you're welcome and thanks again!

Comment: Internet still flaky? ;)

Comment: @Tomalak nearly 4 years now :-) !!! we need to make this into a proper plugin

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It doesn't look like there is anything built-in. But writing an extension isn't too hard:

```
$.fn.assertSize = function(size) { 
  if (this.length != size) { 
    alert("Expected " + size + " elements, but got " + this.length + ".");
    // or whatever, maybe use console.log to be more unobtrusive
  }
  return this;
};
```

Usage is exactly as you propose in your question.

```
$("#btnSignup").assertSize(1).click(function() {
  return validateForm();
);
```

Note that in its current form the function returns successfully even if the assertion fails. Anything you have chained will still be executed. Use `return false;` instead of `return this;` to stop further execution of the chain.

Comment: thanks! theres pretty much infinite scope for how to log or report it but an alert will do for now! i was just hoping someone had already written a plugin. i'm really getting sick and tired of seeing javascript errors on fortune 100 companies - and i want my pages to be as error free as possible

Comment: oh and i've found these kinds of assertions very valuable. would like to get them into jquery itself somehow but never got round to suggesting it and inexpensive runtime checks are a good way to find refactoring bugs

Comment: $.fn.assertSingle = function() { return this.assertSize(1); };

Answer (score 8):

Enhancements to Tomalak’s answer: throw the error to halt execution, include the offending selector and add the `assertSingle` variant.

```
$.fn.assertSize = function(size) {
    if (this.length != size) { 
        throw "Expected " + size + " elements, but selector '" + this.selector + "' found " + this.length + ".";
    }
    return this;
};
$.fn.assertSingle = function() { return this.assertSize(1); };
```

Answer (score 3):

I created a plugin for that: [jquery-assert](https://github.com/timbuethe/jquery-assert). You could use it like this:

Make sure, one or more elements were found, before calling the next function:

```
$('#element01').assertFound().val('x')
```

Assert that 1 element was selected:

```
$('#element01').assertOne(); // same as assertFound(1)
```

Make sure a given number of elements were found before calling further functions:

```
$('.item').assertFound(10).find('p').assertFound(10).data(...)
```

Answer (score -3):

You probably want http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/eq#index:

> Reduce the set of matched elements to a single element.

If your selector returns no objects then jQuery simply won't run the chained code as it has no elements to run them on

Comment: this isn't quite what i'm looking for, but nonetheless was something i wasn't aware of - and might be something i would use in building such an assertion library if i do build one. i explicitly want an error and not null. big danger with jQuery is people tend not to reality check what it returns