# Is there a way to get jQuery selector expression text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of selectors like :

```
var arr = [".discuss .title .post", ".post .desc" , ".eventlist .event"];
```

I want to loop through this array and attach a click event on it.

```
for(var i in arr){
   $(arr[i]).click(function(){
      //here I need the selector i.e. arr[i] expression - for some css work
   });
}
```

Is there a way by which I can get this selector expression inside the click callback function?
I went through this post which has similar problem : [How do I get a jQuery selector's expression as text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500246/how-do-i-get-a-jquery-selectors-expression-as-text)

But as said there, I couldn't find any "selector" attribute of jQuery object. I tried this way:

```
for(var i in arr){
   $(arr[i]).click(function(){
      console.log(jQuery(this).attr('selector')); //This gives undefined
   });
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Your question is "what are JavaScript closures and how do I use them" :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct syntax is `$('.something').selector`. However, `.selector` only works when a selector **string** is explicitly supplied - but there is no selector in `$(this)`.

One workaround is to save a copy of the selector in a function surrounding the `click` function:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { // (Don't use "for-in loop" for arrays)
    (function (selector) { // 2. a copy is saved as the argument "selector"
        $(selector).click(function () {
            console.log(selector);
        });
    }) (arr[i]); // 1. Pass in the selector
}
```

---

Another option is to compare `$(this)` to each selector in your array, using `.is()`:

```
$(arr.join(',')).click(function () { // a quick way to select all selectors
    var selector;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if ($(this).is(arr[i])) {
            selector = arr[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    console.log(selector);
});
```

Comment: Thats awesome! I prefer the first solution and it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Now deprecated : http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#selector-property-on-jquery-objects

Answer (score 0):

You can at least get the class value of each selected element:

```
$(this).attr("class");
```

Doesn't this provide sufficient info for what you intend to do?

Answer (score 0):

I don't seem to get any error, its as though there is no `.click()` event, [**example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Scoobler/ZmC2B/1/)

But if you split your array and attach a click to every item in your array it seems to work for me.

```
// Trouble is you will attach two click's to a class="post" item:
var arr = [".discuss .title .post", ".post .desc" , ".eventlist .event"];

for(var a in arr){
    var ar = arr[a].split(' ');
    for(var i in ar){
        $(ar[i]).click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            var sele = $(this).attr('selector');
            console.log(href); 
            console.log(sele); 
            alert("HREF: "+href+" - Selector: "+sele);
        });
    }
}
```

Take a look at it in action [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Scoobler/ZmC2B/) along with a solution to stopping adding two clicks.