# Retrieve the string representation of a jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, string, selector

With a given jQuery selector `$('#my-id .my-class a')` stored as a variable `jqElement`, how can I return the string representation of that selector?

In other words:

```
jqElement = $('#my-id .my-class a');
jqElement.someFunc(); // returns '#my-id .my-class a'
```

I looked here [How do I get a jQuery selector's expression as text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500246/how-do-i-get-a-jquery-selectors-expression-as-text), but found the information outdated and possibly incomplete.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get a jQuery selector's expression as text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500246/how-do-i-get-a-jquery-selectors-expression-as-text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jqElement.selector
```

will return selector value

Answer (score 3):

As provided in the answers to the question you linked to, the `selector` property is the most appropriate method you'll find.

Whilst it is entirely accurate for basic selectors, you'll find that when using manipulation methods such as `parent()`, `next()` etc, the `.selector` property will get mangled beyond reuse:

```
alert($('foo[id^=fish]:gt(5):eq(4)').selector); // foo[id^=fish]:gt(5):eq(4)
alert($('foo').children('bar').next().selector); // foo.children(bar).next()
```

E.g. you can plug the first straight back into `$()`, but you cannot for the latter.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#my-id .my-class a').selector;
```

Answer (score 2):

The *selector* property exposes a jQuery object's selector. For instance...

```
var cache = $("#my-id .my-class a");

alert(cache.selector); // will alert "#my-id .my-class a"
```