# Get Selector from jQuery(this)

Tags: jquery, this

```
jQuery('table tr td').each(function() {
    console.log ( this );
});
```

In the above example, console.log ( this ); prints:

```
<td valign="top">
    Color: Blue<br>
    Size: M<br>
    <div>Qty: 2</div>
    <div>Price: $14.95</div>
</td>
```

How can I get the current selector, which is "table tr td," from "this"?

I tried using console.log ( jQuery(this).selector ); but it prints nothing.

Comment: You can do `var t = $(this);` and then manipulate t as a jquery object.

Comment: Why do you want to get the selector?

Comment: How would I get the selector "table tr td" from $(this)?

Comment: Rocket, because I need to pass it as a parameter to another function.

Comment: I misunderstood, however I believe `.selector` was removed in JQuery 1.9. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382028/get-the-current-jquery-selector-string) for some more info. Why can you not hard-code the selector when you pass it though? You're not dynamically generating it before hand, and if you *were*, you could just re-use that same declaration.

Comment: @GTSJoe: You *already* know what it is.  Why not just save it in a variable *before* the `.each`?  Something like: `var selector = 'table tr td';  jQuery(selector).each(function(){ console.log(selector); });`.

Comment: I don't know what your second function is doing, but it should be enough to use `$(this)` as a function argument

Comment: @empiric He wants to be able to return `table tr td` from within his `each`, dynamically. You used to be able to use `.selector` but this was deprecated and removed in 1.7 and 1.9, respectively.

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. Show how you're trying to use the selector, and we can probably show how to do it with the supported jQuery API.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a different class attribute to each `<td>` for example.

```js
$('table tr td').each(function() {
    alert($(this).attr("class"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="t1">Color: Blue<br>
    Size: M<br>
    <div>Qty: 2</div>
    <div>Price: $14.95</div></td>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="t2">Color: Red<br>
    Size: L<br>
    <div>Qty: 3</div>
    <div>Price: $15.99</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="t3">Color: Yellow<br>
    Size: M<br>
    <div>Qty: 2</div>
    <div>Price: $14.95</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="t4">Color: LightBlue<br>
    Size: M<br>
    <div>Qty: 4</div>
    <div>Price: $12.95</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I cannot modify the HTML, so this solution will not work.

Comment: you can then add a class or id attribute to each td element lugo and refer to it

Answer (score 0):

Then try the following

```js
var i = 1;
$('table tr td').each(function() {
 $(this).addClass("t" + i);
    alert($(this).attr("class"));
 i++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Color: Blue<br>
    Size: M<br>
    <div>Qty: 2</div>
    <div>Price: $14.95</div></td>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Color: Red<br>
    Size: L<br>
    <div>Qty: 3</div>
    <div>Price: $15.99</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Color: Yellow<br>
    Size: M<br>
    <div>Qty: 2</div>
    <div>Price: $14.95</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Color: LightBlue<br>
    Size: M<br>
    <div>Qty: 4</div>
    <div>Price: $12.95</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```