# How to grab the selector info from the main jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's pretty simple, we have this line. I'd like to grab the info from:

`console.log($('#fourth-step tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(3)'));`

So the output is `#fourth-step tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(3)`.

This outputs a very long object but **I need only the selector information**.

I'm almost sure somewhere already is a thread about this problem but I couldn't find any, sorry.

To make things easier, there is a list of things that I've tried and they didn't work*.

1. `console.log('z' + {obj});`
2. `console.log(JSON.stringify({obj}));`
3. `console.log(String({obj});`

*`{` and `}` - shortcut.*

Any ideas? :)

Comment: This has been asked a lot before and is generally an X/Y question. Instead of storing the selector, store the jQuery object which was created, or dynamically select the elements you require at a later point. If you can explain why you believe you need to do this we will be able to suggest better alternatives.

Comment: You want to use a selector and then, at some point, discover the selector you used?

Comment: @DavidThomas Yea, I need to store that selector info.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you for your detailed comment :) I'd like to do that because I'm creating a tic tac toe game and I'd like to know `tr:nth-child()` and `td:nth-child()`value of this selector. Btw, can you explain what is X/Y question, please?

Comment: If you just want the HTML element associated with the selector you can do `$('#fourth-step tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(3)').get(0)`, is that what you're wanting?

Comment: An X/Y question is where you ask about a problem you have with a flawed solution you're trying to create (X) instead of asking about solving the problem you originally had (Y).

Comment: Also, given those requirements I don't see why you need to store the selectors at all. You can just select the elements when required.

Comment: Storing the jQuery object can have some drawbacks,  I have had issues with the objects getting stale, so I have found using a selector to be much more dependable.

Comment: All jQuery objects are stored in the array and from that array, I have to find `nth-child()` values. Based on the values, then I replace it with a different value but that's a different story.

Comment: It's gonna be a Tic Tac Toe BOT.

Comment: @Jtbs What do you mean "getting stale"? What's gonna happen to them over time? And it's also a selector inside an object, so maybe I don't understand you clearly but "using a selector to be much more dependable" sentence makes no sense for me.

Comment: [Silently LOLing at the ugliness of "abusing" CSS selectors to navigate(?) the DOM of a table in the first place here. The `.rows` and `.cells` collections have existed since DOM Level 1 already ... but hey, today `$ == JavaScript`, am I right kids?]

Comment: Maybe my usage was different and doesn't apply, but if you were to get the jQuery object, then modify the dom separately, perhaps adding or removing elements that would show up using the selector, I don't think the jQuery object changes because the selection was done before the change.

Comment: @CBroe Hehe :D I really didn't know about these two methods. Thank you. `var cell = table.rows[1].cells[1];` seems more simple.

Comment: The hardest part is to get the object's selector as the string. Later I can do everything I want with it. My main purpose is to use `replace()` function to change `nth-child()` values and make it another object with changed position - using `nth-child()`. Maybe there is an easy trick using `cells()` and `rows()` methods?

Comment: Granted, rather special case here, because you were dealing with a table to begin with, so this of course doesn't translate to many other cases, where using `:nth-child` could make more sense, than trying to navigate through the DOM using this method here, that attribute there ... Plus, browsers these days have highly optimized selector engines, so simply "handing the job over" from pure JS to there makes sense, too. But Tic Tac Toe is such a good example for where using a table makes total sense from the HTML point already, so I couldn't pass the chance to remember some "old DOM friends" ;-)

Comment: My game link is here: https://codepen.io/Kestis500/pen/XEKJMX?editors=1010. I'm working on the Player VS Computer mode, that's why I need all your help now :)

Comment: @CBroe Can you say, where using `cells()` and `rows()` makes more sense, or, where `nth-child()` makes more, please? :)

Comment: Well if you just need to get access to cell x in row y to "do something" with it, then I would certainly go for table.rows[y].cells[x] here. Need to set a specific class? `table.rows[y].cells[x].classList.add('foo')` Need to switch out the cell content, to mark a player's choice? `table.rows[y].cells[x].innerHTML='X'` ... what else, any other operations you where trying to locate a specific cell for using nth-child?

Comment: @CBroe So I should always use your suggested methods instead of `:nth-child()` if it's not a CSS-Free project, right? :) However, none of the answers answered to my problem, don't know what to do now.

Comment: No, as I said, rather special case here. The table already expresses the "grid" structure of rows and columns of a TTT game quite nicely, and since it also already provides methods to easily locate row y and "column" (cell) x, I'd use them here _in this instance_. _"However, none of the answers answered to my problem, don't know what to do now"_ - well I am not exactly sure what problem you are trying to solve now? The necessity of "caching" any selectors in string form should be gone now, with this easy way to locate any cell at any time?

Comment: Yes, maybe, but I'll need to replace this number depending on the user choice so the player will never win against the computer. Can you wait a sec, so I can try to accomplish your suggested method, please?

Comment: Why using your method doesn't work for me? :/ Using non-jquery selector it worked: `document.getElementById('fourth-step').rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML = 'asdasd';
`. https://jsfiddle.net/oerxtgfc/

Comment: Because a) you can not just call DOM methods on a jQuery object, you need either `$('#fourth-step')[0].rows...` (shortcut for https://api.jquery.com/get/) or go "fully back to DOM" in the first place, `document.querySelector('#fourth-step').rows...`, and b) the DOM has no `.text()` method either, that's why I mentioned innerHTML: https://jsfiddle.net/oerxtgfc/3/

Comment: I've done everything how you said and it worked, however, I still can't access my selector. Now I don't get a big object, instead, I just got an element `<td></td>`. How to access information where is it's place in the table? https://jsfiddle.net/fd4hv4tx/

Comment: If nobody will answer this question, I'm just going to use basic `#id` stuff and it won't bother me so much :D Maybe that's the solution.

Comment: _"How to access information where is it's place in the table?"_ - what do you mean by "place in the table"? Don't say the "coordinates", as in x/y, as in those two values you just used to _get_ the reference to the table cell object ...?

Comment: I mean how to get the value of method `cells[...]` or `rows[...]` after they were executed for later use? How to get these numbers? E.g. if `...` was `2`, then, how to get 2 later associated with this element?

Comment: I'll use class name of `field`, so it's going to be very straightforward but I'm just curious about these two methods you provided recently :)

Comment: Just go read up a little on what DOM properties there are for different types of elements. For example, there's https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/rowIndex and a corresponding HTMLTableCellElement.cellIndex, so if `var specialCell = tableElement.rows[5].cells[2]`, then go check what `specialCell.cellIndex` contains afterwards. (row index is _on_ the row element, so one level up - `specialCell.parentNode.rowIndex`)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has the `.selector()` method but is deprecated since it doesn't return - at times - the desired result. Try out this jQuery plugin that I've written to get a more unique CSS selector:

```js
$.fn.extend({
  getSelector: function() {
    var path = [],
      currentElement = this[0];

    while (currentElement.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'html') {
      var selector = currentElement.nodeName.toLowerCase();

      if (currentElement.id)
        selector += '#' + currentElement.id;

      if (!currentElement.id && currentElement.className)
        selector += '.' + currentElement.className;

      path.push(selector);

      currentElement = currentElement.parentNode;
    }

    return path.reverse().join(' > ');
  }
});
```

Check out this git repo: [jQuery Plugins Library](https://github.com/bukharim96/jqplus)

Comment: `console.log({obj}.getSelector())` throws an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined`.

Comment: `{obj}` needs to be a `jQuery` object since this is a jQuery Plugin.

Comment: Eg: `console.log($('#myElement').getSelector())` for instance returns: `div > div#myElement` (absolute selector).

Comment: It is :D `console.log($('#fourth-step tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(3)').getSelector());`.

Comment: @lukas-naujokaitis there's no HTML markup in your fiddle.

Comment: Ah, yea, my bad :D But there is another problem: `body > div.outer-container > div.container text-center > div#fourth-step > table > tbody > tr > td` doesn't show the `nth-child()` value of `tr` and `td` element's. https://jsfiddle.net/8dy3t4dz/

Comment: I haven't yet added support for psuedo selectors.

Comment: Is it hard to do so?

Comment: I haven't given it an attempt yet. But you could raise an issue on the repo, and I'll take it into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Until jQuery 1.7, there was [selector](https://api.jquery.com/selector/) property, but it's now deprecated. The best you can do is to store the selector as a property of the element, like this:

```
$(selector).data('selector',selector)
```

Note that after moving or cloning your element around in the page, the selector may not match anymore the element. This may be the reason behind the deprecation of `selector` property.

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382028/get-the-current-jquery-selector-string)

Comment: It doesn't work. Gives me `undefined` - https://jsfiddle.net/y7rzdkao/.

Comment: I guess changing jQuery version to 1.7 isn't gonna be a good idea, right? :) https://jsfiddle.net/9od8k9xb/

Comment: `selector` should be a variable containing your CSS selector

Comment: It's not inherently wrong to downgrade, but I wouldn't advice so.